# nginx is unable to open (and thus serve) files despite proper filesystem permissions

Tags: nginx, permissions

After a fresh installation of nginx 1.4.7 on Fedora 20 I added two additional locations
to the the default location:

```
user  neradis; # I also tried the 'root' user here and commenting this directive out, to no avail
worker_processes  1;

[...]
http {

include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile        on;

[...]

index   index.html index.htm;

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
autoindex    on;

    location /music/ {
        root    /home/neradis/audio;
    autoindex    on;     
}

location /nginx_test/ {
        root /;  
    autoindex on;
}


    error_page  404              /404.html;
    location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
    }
}
}
```

nginx serves files from the default location `/usr/share/nginx/html` without problem, but yields errors denied permissions for filesystem operations (`open()`, `opendir()`) for the added locations. I am aware that every parent directory must the 'executable' for the user used by nginx, so I ensured that using `namei -l`:

```
f: /nginx_test/file.txt
drwxr-xr-x root    root    /
drwxrwxrwx neradis neradis nginx_test
-rwxrwxrwx neradis neradis file.txt
```

Nonetheless, I still get a 403 response on a `wget localhost/nginx_test/file.txt`, finding this error in the logs:

```
[error] 6950#0: *1 open() "/nginx_test/file.txt" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /nginx_test/file.txt HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
```

I get the same errors for the `/home/neradis/audio/music`. I am puzzled what the crucial difference to the working functioning default root `/usr/share/nginx/html` is:

```
f: /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
drwxr-xr-x root root /
drwxr-xr-x root root usr
drwxr-xr-x root root share
drwxr-xr-x root root nginx
drwxr-xr-x root root html
-rw-r-xr-x root root index.html
```

Any ideas what else might keep nginx from accessing the files?

**edit (solution):** The comments guided me in the right direction. The file permissions we're okay, but SELinux prevented reading the files in the new locations, as they had (SELinux) types of `default_t` and `user_home_t`, that we're forbidden for the `httpd_t`. I wrote my own selinux module to allow for `default_t` files and enabled access for the home files with `setsebool -P http_read_user_content`.

Comment: Check `/var/log/audit/audit.log`.

Comment: Are you aware of SELinux ?

Comment: This will almost certainly be an SELinux issue.

Comment: Thanks, M. Hampton and lain, for the pointers in the right direction. This was the first time I was confronted with unwanted SELinux blocks, so I was unaware of the whole SELinux machinery until today.

Answer (score 0):

Are the files for `/music/` location located in `/home/neradis/audio/music` directory? If not, then you should use alias:

```
location /music {
    alias /home/neradis/audio;
}
```

This is one of the most common pitfalls in nginx configuration, that is, one uses `root` directive inside locations, when `alias` is the proper one.

nginx adds the matched location URI after the `root` directory specified inside location, while with `alias`, the URI is stripped off.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but the issue I am describing here is clearly not an issue of nginx not finding the files. I already did a 'countercheck' by configuring another location that pointed to an non-existing directory and in this case I got a proper 404 and a different message in the error log.

Answer (score 0):

The default user used by nginx is/should be the www-data user, not root. 
You could also create another user, and add him to the www-data.

When adding other locations, I suggest you to:

- create some others virtualhosts, and do not use the default virtualhost.
- put your data in directories readable/writeable by www-data, /var/www for example.

Comment: A side note: In Fedora the default user for nginx is 'nginx', not 'www-data'. I also (re-)tried to use this default user ('nginx') and made the whole `/nginx_test` directory owned by the nginx user. The errors stay the same.